# Google Visualization not working with appscript html service

Tags: google-apps-script, google-visualization, google-sites, google-caja

I want to use appscript htmlservice along with appscript,
The html service seems to work but the visualization do not work.
Here is the code for reference.
Code.GS :

```
// Script-as-app template.
function doGet() {
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('html_visualization');
}
```

html_visualization.html

```
    <html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>    
  <script type="text/javascript">

   google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});
   google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
   function drawChart() {

   var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();     
      data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');     
        data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
         data.addRows([          
        ['Mushrooms', 3],
         ['Onions', 1],
         ['Olives', 1],
         ['Zucchini', 1],
         ['Pepperoni', 2]
         ]);
         var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night','width':400, 'height':300};
          var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById ('chart_div') );        
           chart.draw(data, options);
     }

       </script> 

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
    Hello World
  </body>

       </html>
```

When published Hello world appears but no sign of the chart.

Comment: For others arriving at this question the Google Visualisation API should be fully accessible using the IFRAME sandbox mode in HtmlService

Answer (score 7):

HtmlService uses Caja to filter the unsafe Javascript, CSS and html from your HTML page and then it renders the filetered content to the browser.
As I tested your code at Caja playground, It shows same behavior, so this is the issue with Caja, not Htmlservice.
You may test your Html file at [Caja Payground](http://caja.appspot.com)

Steps to test your HTML file

1. Copy your HTML file code to "Source" Tab at [Caja Playground](http://caja.appspot.com)
2. Hit Cajole button
3. After some time, Rendered result Tab will show you the result

You may report this issue in [Caja issue Tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/issues/list)

Answer (score 2):

Waqar is correct, but visualization support is coming.

Comment: Good to know that. Waiting eagerly for that feature

Comment: I look forward to that support.